# how to fetch data in mongoDb using Asp.net with button click and I know username only

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am facing problem in asp.net for fetching data from MongoDB and got an error. Please help me to resolve this error.
Error :

> Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType 'Null'.Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'ObjectId' from BsonType
>   'Null'.

```
   public partial class Loginpage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connectionstring = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionstring);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("SIH");
            bool isMongoLive = database.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}").Wait(1000);
            if (isMongoLive)
            {
                var collection = database.GetCollection<userinfo>("userinfo");
                // var id = new ObjectId("5a6b35217e60af482bedef33");
                var idd = TextBox1.Text;
                //var userinfo = collection.Find(b => b._id == id).ToListAsync().Result;
                var userinfo = collection.Find(b => b.name == idd).ToListAsync().Result; // Due to this i got an error

                foreach (var user in userinfo)
                {
                    Response.Write(user.phoneno);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Hello dude your server is not connected !! ");
            }
        }
    }


    public class userinfo
    {
        //public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string emailid { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string phoneno { get; set; }
        public string activate { get; set; }
        public string block { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like in SIH collection one of your documents has a null ObjectId

You can make your code work by making _id nullable `public ObjectId? _id { get; set; }`